# Calculate handling time per user based on timestamps and status changes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have one table.

```
user_id | status  | timestamp
null    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:01:00
null    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:02:00
7461    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:03:00
null    | open    | 2022-05-05 01:04:00
null    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:06:00
null    | on hold | 2022-05-05 01:09:00
8474    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:10:00
null    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:11:00
null    | solved  | 2022-05-05 01:12:00
2638    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:13:00
null    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:16:00
5721    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:17:00
```

I need to find the handling time for each user i.e. the time difference from when a user_id is assigned and the first status change. Also, if there is no status change until the next user is assigned, then I need to find the time difference from when the first user_id is assigned to when the next user_id is assigned.

The output I'm looking for is

```
user_id | timestamp
7461    | 00:01:00
8474    | 00:02:00
2638    | 00:04:00
```

I've been working on this for hours and I can't seem to get the right result. I know that a CTE would work but I don't know how to put in the conditions correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I've tried and it works in MySQL. But I cannot use MySQL in this case.

```
   SELECT t1.user_id,
      MIN(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp))) AS timestamp
FROM tab t1
INNER JOIN tab t2
       ON t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp
      AND t1.user_id IS NOT NULL
      AND t2.status IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY t1.user_id
```

Comment: @DaleK I've added my attempt.

Comment: You didn't provide whole data

Comment: @RF1991 could you please tell me what you mean by that? I did provide the table I have and the result I wanted

Comment: Can you explain in details how do you obtain the required result. Include the necessary calculations

Comment: @Squirrel I don’t know how to get the required result, which is why I’m asking for help.

Comment: many user_id and status are null hence getting your desired result is impossible @an_analyst

Comment: How do you obtain `7461 | 00:01:00` ? or `8474 | 00:02:00` etc ?

Comment: @Squirrel as I mentioned in the question, that is the time difference between when a user is assigned and the only the first status change

Answer (score 0):

use `APPLY` operator to find the next `timestamp` and find the `datediff()`. Convert to `time` data type for your required result

```
select t.user_id, 
       convert(time(0), dateadd(second, datediff(second, t.timestamp, n.timestamp), 0))
from   tab t
       cross apply
       (
           select timestamp = min(x.timestamp)
           from   tab x
           where  x.timestamp > t.timestamp
           and    (
                       x.status  <> t.status
                  or   (x.status is null and t.status is not null)
                  or   (x.status is not null and t.status is null)
                  or   x.user_id <> t.user_id
                  )
       ) n
where  t.user_id   is not null
and    n.timestamp is not null
```

Note : the above query is for `SQL Server`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how to apply this in snowflake database though?

Comment: No idea. You originally tagged the question as `SQL Server`. This works under `SQL Server`